# Twitter Bootstrap Button Dropdown with Nav Doesn't Work

Tags: jquery, twitter-bootstrap

I am working on creating a dropdown menu for buttons and I cannot get the dropdown to work when the navbar dropdown menus exist (http://jsfiddle.net/8XTkq/1/)

I have tried this with the example from the twitter bootstrap page (copied and pasted) and it doesn't want to work. I have also tried it with a link and that did not work either...

```
<div class="btn-group">
  <a class="btn btn-primary" href="#"><i class="icon-user icon-white"></i> User</a>
  <a class="btn btn-primary dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" href="#"><span class="caret"></span></a>
  <ul class="dropdown-menu">
<li><a href="#"><i class="icon-pencil"></i> Edit</a></li>
<li><a href="#"><i class="icon-trash"></i> Delete</a></li>
<li><a href="#"><i class="icon-ban-circle"></i> Ban</a></li>
<li class="divider"></li>
<li><a href="#"><i class="i"></i> Make admin</a></li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

What could I be missing?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When using external resources in JSFiddle please include them in the "external resources" panel on the left, not directly in the code. Also, put CSS and JS into their appropriate box's. Once I did that everything worked.
JSFiddle: http://bit.ly/13KmiJu (sorry SO won't let me include direct JSFiddle links without code)

Comment: That is very interesting... I tried adding all of the externals to JSFiddle and it still didn't work for me. When I grabbed the externals in the order that you have them, it works. Thank you very much.

Comment: No problem :). Have fun coding!